# MIPS: How to print an integer(neg or pos) as a character string?

Tags: mips, mips32, mips64

```
addi $t0,$t0,4
```

How can i print this $t0 as a character string? Is there a syscall method for that?

Comment: What do you mean? Say $t0 contains 65, what do you want printed: "65", 'A', "sixty-five"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, code 11. The character to print should go in `$a0`

```
li $v0, 11
move $a0, $t0
syscall
```